# Using unique id's in div's to show/hide in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, unique

I'm having some difficulties writing code to catch the 'id' name from the  to open the requested .

I have three boxes:

```
<div>
<h3>Box 1</h3>
<p><a id="box2" href="#">Show Box 2</a></p>
</div>

<div id="box2">
<h3>Box 2</h3>
<p><a id="box3" href="#">Show Box 3</a></p>
</div>

<div id="box3">
<h3>Box 3</h3>
<p>TBD</p>
</div>
```

And I am trying to catch the 'id' from the  tag to open the respected  with that 'id'. For example, a id="box2" will open div id="box2".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div#" + getName).hide();
$('a#' + getName).click(function() {
    $('div#' + getName).show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

I'm not sure if jQuery is sensitive to single or double quotes, or if I am approaching this incorrectly. Any help is appreciated. Have an outstanding day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the same "id" value for more than one element on a page, period. That's what "id" means.

One way to relate one element to another is to use a "data-" attribute:

```
<button data-friend="something">Click Me</button>

<div id='something'> ... </div>
```

The jQuery library will give you the value of a "data-" attribute via the ".data()" API:

```
var friend = $('button').data('something');
var friendDiv = $('#' + friend);
```

You can also use class values to relate elements together.

Comment: To reference all three divs you should use a class for them, so do something like: `class="clickyDivs"` in the div tags, then use `$(".clickyDivs")` to get all of them, and then inside your click function you should be able to do `this.show();`

Comment: Would you recommend that I use the data-friend attribute over class? I tried assembling something based on your suggestion, however it does not show the requested div's:

$('div.hidden').hide();

$('.expandBox').click(function() {
  var friend = $('a').data('something');
  var friendDiv = $('#' + friend);

  $('div' + friendDiv).show();
});

    <div>
    <h3>Box 1</h3>
    <p><a data-friend="box2" class="expandBox" href="#">Show Box 2</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden" id="box2">
    <h3>Box 2</h3>
    <p><a data-friend="box3" class="expandBox" href="#">Show Box 3</a></p>
    </div>

Comment: Well you can use either one.  If you're using an old version of jQuery (prior to 1.4), then the ".data()" trick won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm assuming to avoid the problem of version compatibility, if I just use a class=box3, how can I pull that class name and use it to show the div?

Comment: Yes - you can get the class from the anchor (or whatever it is that's the target of the event), and use that as an "id" value to find the "partner" element.

Comment: Oh and you can get the class by checking the "class" or "className" attribute.

Comment: I wrote this:

$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.hidden").hide();

$("a").click(function ( event ) {
  var id = $("a").attr("class");
  $("div#" + id).show();
});
});

However, it stops working after opening Box 2. Your continued help is appreciated.

HTML: <div>
<h3>Box 1</h3>
<a class="box2" href="#">Open Box 2</a>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="box2">
<h3>Box 2</h3>
<a class="box2" href="#">Open Box 3</a>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="box3">
<h3>Box 3</h3>
</div>

Comment: OK well the thing is, it's kind-of tough to read the HTML/JavaScript in these comments :-)  Instead of `$('a').attr("class")` in the event handler, try `$(this).attr("class")` - that will get the "class" value from the `<a>` tag that was actually clicked.

Comment: Also, when you're fetching something by "id", you don't really need to have `"div#" + id` -- just `"#" + id` is enough, because "id" values are unique.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, @Pointy. While I have you, if I wanted to to close the parent div from within it, would a simple $(this).parent("div").hide(); work? Thank you again, you have been a tremendous help.

Comment: Well `.closest('div')` is what I would use, because it's more forgiving if you make tweaks to your HTML - it means to look up the chain of parent elements until it finds a `<div>`, whereas ".parent()" only looks at the immediate parent.

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique. Try using a class as a selector.

```
$("div." + getClass).hide();
```